# Prove that $ I + J = R \iff b + J $ is invertible in $ R / J$, where $ I = \langle b \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $I, J$ its ideals, where $I = \langle b \rangle$, for a $ b \in R$. Prove that $ I + J = R \iff b + J $ is invertible in $ R / J$

If it is a duplicate, I apologize, but I've already looked up for it. 
I was able to show this: 
$ I + J = R \iff (\forall r \in R)  r = i + j $, for some $ i \in I, j \in J \iff (\forall r \in R) r = ba + j $, for some $ a \in R, j \in J$. Am I missing something or am I in a completely wrong direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.  Note that $R$ is an integral domain, so it contains the unity.  Thus, $I+J=R$ if and only if $1\in I+J$.  That is, $I+J=R$ iff $ab+j=1$ for some $a\in R$ and $j\in J$.  (That is, you only have to take $r$ to be $1$ in your attempt.)  What next?

Comment: Well, if ab + j = 1, for some a, that means that b is invertible in R / J, because R / J = r + J = {r + j : j \in J}, so for j = 0 (which is in J), ab + j= 1 + 0, i.e. b is invertible. Am I right?

Comment: @NemanjaBeric  I would write it in the following way: $ab+j=1$ implies $ab+J=1+J$.  Thus, $(a+J)(b+J)=1+J$.  That is, $a+J\in R/J$ is the inverse of $b+J\in R/J$.

Comment: Right, right. I must not omit the "+ J"